# INSERT INTO MSSQL from textfile contains NULL values on INTEGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, insert, null

I have problems to insert/bulk NULL values from textfile into MSSQL.
When replace NULL value with a number it works with no problem.
2 Columns is set to ALLOW NULLS,

PublicationCaption and PublicationNumber

Here is example of text file

> 1#DI#Dagens Industri#435#358#2016-10-19
>   2#DN#Dagens Nyheter#NULL#359#2016-10-19

I think there is some problem with the foreach loop in code where I need add something to make this work.

Here is the code I'm using

```
public static DataTable Publication()
    {

        DataTable dtPublication = new DataTable();

        dtPublication.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[6] { new DataColumn("ID", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
        new DataColumn("PublicationCode", System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("PublicationCaption",System.Type.GetType("System.String")),
        new DataColumn("PublicationNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
        new DataColumn("ProductNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32")),
        new DataColumn("CreatedDate", System.Type.GetType("System.DateTime")),

        });

        for (int i = 0; i < dtPublication.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            dtPublication.Columns[i].AllowDBNull = true;
        }

        string txtData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Publication2.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        foreach (string row in txtData.Split('\n'))
        {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
            {

                dtPublication.Rows.Add();

                int i = 0;
                foreach (string cell in row.Split('#'))
                {

                    dtPublication.Rows[dtPublication.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;

                    i++;

                }
            }
        }

        return dtPublication;
    }
```

Im getting (The input string had an incorrect format. Unable to store  in the PublicationNumber column. Type Int32 is expected.) when DEBUGGING.

Please I need some advise, help with this to solve the problem. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: What if in string instead of WORD NULL there would be empty space ? Like 

1#DI#Dagens Industri#435#358#2016-10-19 2#DN#Dagens Nyheter##359#2016-10-19

Comment: If it's an int use `int.Parse(cell)`. In general, use the debugger. What is the value of cell when it fails?

Comment: @Whencesoever it´s getting me an error to like this (
The input string had an incorrect format. Unable to store <> in the PublicationNumber column. Type Int32 is expected)

Comment: @TimSchmelter value of cell when fails is "NULL"

Comment: @HenriThiesen: then you have the answer, how can a string `"NULL"` be  translated to a number?

Answer (score 0):

The database doesn't know that the "NULL" string you try to insert actually means a null value. To fix this, change the "NULL" string to DBNull.Value:

```
if (cell == "NULL")
   dtPublication.Rows[dtPublication.Rows.Count - 1][i] = DBNull.Value;
else
   dtPublication.Rows[dtPublication.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
```

Comment: This dosent work the foreach loop gets wrong Im getting (
The input string had an incorrect format. Unable to store <DI> in the ID column. Type Int32 is expected.)

Comment: This solution works as well forgotten add i++ in the end 1+

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature that translates a string `"NULL"` to a nullable field in a `DataTable`. You have to implement it yourself:

```
object value = DBNull.Value;
if(!"NULL".Equals(cell, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    value = cell;
dtPublication.Rows[dtPublication.Rows.Count - 1][i] = value;
```

Comment: How can this be implemented? Im getting worng syntax The name 'StringComparsion' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @HenriThiesen: look at my answer ;)

Comment: I see now StringComparison was spelled wrong from start ;) Anyway I think this is the solution but my foreachloop jumps over ID now and start on second column when implement this.

Comment: 1+ Now works I forgotten to add the i++; in the end. Thanks @Tim Schmelter

Comment: @HenriThiesen: feel free to upvote or accept answers :)